# Simple jquery ajax content loading not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Hi guys i have a problem with this script. It is not working. It should load page to my content same as the script below.

JS - not working

```
$("#buttons img").click(function(){
  var data_trick = $(this).attr("data-trick");
  $.ajax({
    url: data_trick+".php",
    success:function(result){
    $("#content").html(result);
  }}); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="buttons">
  <img data-trick="forward_spin" src="images/previous_button.svg">   
  <img data-trick="backward_spin" src="images/next_button.svg">    
</div>
```

I have already made a similar one which is perfectly working

JS - working

```
   $("#ul_menu li ul li").click(function(){
    $("#ul_menu li ul li").removeClass("sub_active"); 
    $(this).addClass("sub_active"); 
    var data_trick = $(this).attr("data-trick");
  $.ajax({
    url: data_trick+".php",
    success:function(result){
      $("#content").html(result);
    }}); 
  });
```

HTML

```
<ul id="ul_menu">
    <li id="basics"><span>Basic tricks</span>
        <ul> 
            <li data-trick="forward_spin" >Forward/Split Spin</li>
            <li data-trick="backward_spin" >Backward/Split Spin</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
...
```

Comment: whether the code is added under dom ready callback

Comment: Use chrome dev tools to see what's being sent back - see the "response" tab

Comment: Check in console tab if there is any JS error too. If you don't know where it is - default trigger of dev tool is F12

Comment: Try var data_trick = $(this).find('img').attr("data-trick"); to be more specific ot get data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start console logging things. Add...

```
console.log($(this));
```

...after...

```
$("#buttons img").click(function(){
```

...so you see what's actually being clicked on. Then...

```
console.log(result);
```

...after the ajax success. Keep doing that till you see where the breakage is.

Comment: Thx a lot but i already repaired it
    $('#buttons img').live("click", function() {

Comment: Oh yeah, if it's not visible at the time of binding, it won't trigger a click event. I recommend ".off().on('click', function..." or just ".on('click'...", cause .live() has been deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/live/